# Loop filters containing a list of keywords (one key word each time) in a specific column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the loop function to perform filters containing a list of different keywords (i.e different reference numbers) in a specific column (i.e. CaseText) but just filter one keyword each time so that I do not have to manually change the keyword each time. I want to see the result in the form of dataframe.

Unfortunately, my code doesn't work. It just returns the whole dataset.

Anyone can help and find out what's wrong with my code? Additionally, it will be great if the resultant table will be broken into different results of each keyword.

Many thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)

list_of_files = ['https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/c1d/Open%20Data%20Planning%20Q1%2019-20%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/9wj/Open%20Data%20Planning%202018-19%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/my7/Planning%20Decisions%202017-2018%20non%20geo.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/303/Planning%20Decisions%202016-2017%20non%20geo.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/zf1/Planning%20Decisions%202015-2016%20non%20geo.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/9b3/Open%20Data%20Planning%202014-2015%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/6zz/Open%20Data%20Planning%202013-2014%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/r7m/Open%20Data%20Planning%202012-2013%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/fzw/Open%20Data%20Planning%202011-2012%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/x3w/Open%20Data%20Planning%202010-2011%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/tbc/Open%20Data%20Planning%202009-2010%20-%20NG.csv']

data_container = []
for filename in list_of_files:
  print(filename)
  df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='mac_roman')
  data_container.append(df)

all_data = pd.concat(data_container)

reference_list = ['H/04522/11','15/07697/FUL'] # I want to filter the dataset with a single keyword each time. Because I have nearly 70 keywords to filter. 

select_data = pd.DataFrame()
for keywords in reference_list:
    select_data = select_data.append(all_data[all_data['CaseText'].str.contains("reference_list", na=False)])

select_data = select_data[['CaseReference', 'CaseDate', 'ServiceTypeLabel', 'CaseText', 
                           'DecisionDate', 'Decision', 'AppealRef']]
select_data.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
select_data
```

Comment: change `select = data[data['CaseText'].str.contains("keywords", na=False)]` to `select = data[data['CaseText'].str.contains(keywords, na=False)]`

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. The returned table doesn't filter accordingly. Any more ideas?

Comment: these keyword 'hH/02159/13','16/4324/FUL' do not exist in any `data['CaseText']`. can you find by hand one keyword that you know exists so i can help our with the code.

Comment: I can confirm 'H/04522/11','15/07697/FUL' ,'17/6062/FUL' exist in the `data['CaseText']`. When I filter them separately, I can find out some records. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i can not find any of the 3 in there. Can you share one instance where you find any of the  ` 'H/04522/11','15/07697/FUL' ,'17/6062/FUL' ` in `data['CaseText']` i.e. what is one such specific element of df['CaseText']

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion. In my own code, I have merged a few more datasets but I didn't put that in my initial question. I thought it would be easier to ask for help with simplified code. I have now updated my initial code above. For instance, this in `data['CaseText']` should come up _'Submission of details of condition No.6 (refuse) and No.11(Construction Management Plan) pursuant to planning permission Ref: H/04522/11 dated: 2632012.'_

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that the items in `reference_container` do not match any of the values in column `'CaseReference'`.  Once you figure out which `CaseReference` numbers you want to search for then the below code should work for you.  Just put the correct `CaseReference` numbers in  the `reference_container` list.

```
import pandas as pd

url = ('https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/fzw/'
       'Open%20Data%20Planning%202011-2012%20-%20NG.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='mac_roman')

reference_list = ['hH/02159/13','16/4324/FUL']

select_data = pd.DataFrame()
for keywords in reference_list:
    select_data = select_data.append(data[data['CaseReference'] == keywords],
                                     ignore_index=True)

select_data = select_data[['CaseDate', 'ServiceTypeLabel', 'CaseText', 
                           'DecisionDate', 'Decision', 'AppealRef']]
select_data.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
select_data
```

Comment: Thank you @Rickey. But I don't intend to filter the dataset by the reference numbers in column 'CaseReference'. But only the column `'CaseText'` and find out the entries that contain the specific reference numbers in the `reference_container list` . Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)

list_of_files = ['https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/c1d/Open%20Data%20Planning%20Q1%2019-20%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/9wj/Open%20Data%20Planning%202018-19%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/my7/Planning%20Decisions%202017-2018%20non%20geo.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/303/Planning%20Decisions%202016-2017%20non%20geo.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/zf1/Planning%20Decisions%202015-2016%20non%20geo.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/9b3/Open%20Data%20Planning%202014-2015%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/6zz/Open%20Data%20Planning%202013-2014%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/r7m/Open%20Data%20Planning%202012-2013%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/fzw/Open%20Data%20Planning%202011-2012%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/x3w/Open%20Data%20Planning%202010-2011%20-%20NG.csv',
 'https://open.barnet.gov.uk/download/2nq32/tbc/Open%20Data%20Planning%202009-2010%20-%20NG.csv']

# this takes some time
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(el, engine='python' ) for el in list_of_files]) # read all csvs


reference_list = ['H/04522/11','15/07697/FUL']

reference_dict = dict() # create an empty dictionary.
# Will populate this where each key will be the keyword and each value will be a dataframe 
# filtered for 'CaseText' contain the keyword


for el in reference_list:
    reference_dict[el] = df[(df['CaseText'].str.contains(el)) & ~(df['CaseText'].isna())]
# notice the two conditions
# 1) the column CaseText should contain the keyword. (df['CaseText'].str.contains(el))
# 2) there are some elements in CaseText that are NaN so they need to be excluded 
# this is what ~(df['CaseText'].isna()) does

# you can see the resulting dataframes like so: reference_dict[keyword]. for example
reference_dict['H/04522/11']
```

UPDATE

if you want one dataframe to include the cases where any of the keywords is in the column CaseText try this

```
# lets start after having read in the data

# Seperate your keywords with | in one string.
keywords = 'H/04522/11|15/07697/FUL' # read into regular expressions to understand this

final_df = df[(df['CaseText'].str.contains(keywords)) & ~(df['CaseText'].isna())]

final_df
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But still, in this case, I will have to manually change the keywords in  `reference_dict` each time? My goal is to pull up all the filtered results from the `reference list` in one go. Any ideas about how to achieve that?

Comment: So you want one dataframe with all the keywords. Check the updated  code

Comment: Thank you @dititris_ps. I was thinking to have all the filtered results from the `reference list` by breaking them down into a separate data frame for each keyword. So similar to your previous code with a data frame for each result, but I want to pull all the results of all the keywords in one go. Compared to the new code (using or), this will help visualize the results better by breaking up the results. But perhaps this may not be achievable via Python?